# How to export or convert Ansible playbook to a Bash script?

Tags: ansible

I need to export a rather long Ansible playbook to a Bash script.

The idea is to have a bash script that runs the same commands that Ansible would run from the playbook if the playbook was executed, with all Ansible variables properly resolved.

I need this because I want to run this playbook's commands sequence in an environment where Ansible does not exist or is not used.

Comment: Note that Ansible playbooks are not using bash, they are using python scripts that are shipped to nodes then executed. Is your your machine "with no Ansible" equiped with python3?

Comment: You can't "export an Ansible playbook to a bash script". You could *write* a bash script that accomplishes the same thing as your playbook, which is what we did in the old days before we had decent configuration management tools, but you would need to figure out what commands correspond to the actions of Ansible modules like `service` or `package` or `template`, etc...

Comment: Larsks, thank you for your comment. It sounds like an answer to me.